# Android : Recover data with parcelable object

Tags: android, object, parcelable

-- Problem Solved --

I want to send an object present in my "Activity1" to my "Activity2". To do that, i'm using Parcelable.

I have a class User which implements Parcelable.

In my first activity, i create a user (for test), like this :

```
            User userTest = new User("Name", "FirstName", "AdressTest", 1, "99999", "Nice guy", "pic.jpg",null);
```

And i call the next activity with that :

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(
        MainActivity.this,
        UserProfile.class
    );
    intent.putExtra("userParce", userTest);
    startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is, when i want to show the data of this user in my Activity2, i do that :

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   User user_current = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("userParce");
   Log.i("User Name", user_current.getName());
   Log.i("User FirstName", user_current.getFirstName());
   Log.i("User Adress", user_current.getAdress());
   etc...
```

The problem is that ONLY the "Name" and the Firstname are showing, others are "null", and i don't understand why :'(

Someone to help me ?

PS :

I don't show all the code, because it's useless, with that, there is just a constructor, and my getters.

```
    @Override
public int describeContents()
{
    return 0;
}

    @Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
{
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(firstName);
    dest.writeString(adress);
    dest.writeInt(numberTest);
    dest.writeString(code);
    dest.writeString(description);
    dest.writeString(image);
    dest.writeList(listObject);
}

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<User> CREATOR = new      Parcelable.Creator<User>()
{
    @Override
    public UsercreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
    {
        return new User(source);
    }

    @Override
    public User[] newArray(int size)
    {
    return new User[size];
    }
};

    public static Parcelable.Creator<User> getCreator()
{
    return CREATOR;
}

    public User(Parcel in) {
    this.name= in.readString();
    this.firstName= in.readString();
    this.numberTest= in.readInt();
    this.code = in.readString();
    this.description = in.readString();
    this.image = in.readString();
    this.listObject = null;
}
```

Comment: show us your `Parcelable` implementation

Comment: OMG, i found the problem, very stupid x) I forgot a line in " public User(Parcel in)".....

Comment: Your class is called `User` but your `Parcelable` implementation constructor is `Snack`. which you've now changed ..